# Adding plugins to Phonegap (3.1.0) Cleaver app not working

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm building a hybrid application based on native iOS with parts over Cordova 3.1.0 (known as Cleaver component). The app is working with the sample index.html and it shows the "DEVICE IS READY" message (I suppose it means it's working fine). The problem now is how to add a custom plugin for communicating the native and the Phonegap components.

I've followed some tutorials:

http://moduscreate.com/building-a-custom-phonegap-plugin-for-ios/
http://devgirl.org/2013/09/17/how-to-write-a-phonegap-3-0-plugin-for-android/  (this one for Android)

I've tried installing the "connectivity" plugin on a base/canonical Cordova and copying the structure and the .m and .h to my project, and adding it's own config.xml part, but it didn't work.

Does anyone knows another resource for looking in, or someone else has been in the same situation?

Thanks!

Edited:

I've tested my custom plugin on a new created Cordova project and it works like a charm.

Edited #2:

Making a debug on the Phonegap Cleaver classes, most of it on the CDVViewController, I did realize that the UIWebView Delegate Methods are not being called:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView
- (void)webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError*)error
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

Is there a way for it to reasign the delegate for them to be called?

Answer (score 2):

You've probably already figured out the answer to your question about the UIWebView Delegate Methods not being called, but I wanted to provide an answer for anyone else who may stumble onto this page (I came across this post several times while trying to figure it out).

I assume your project uses ARC as mine does and that is where the problem lies. If you follow the instructions at:
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_ios_webview.md.html#iOS%20WebViews_using_cdvviewcontroller

It tells you to "Instantiate a new CDVViewController and retain it somewhere, e.g., to a class property", but in the example they provide, they don't retain the variable.

Instead make sure you assign the variable to a property:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) CDVViewController *cdvViewController;

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.cdvViewController = [CDVViewController new];
    [self.cdvViewController.view setFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:self.cdvViewController.view];
}
```

And now those delegate methods will be called. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In fact, I've decided to make a native project for every platform but I'll try it in my next project and add the mark of right answer!